# Visual Studio Team explorer builder doesn't find existing files

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure

I'm currently trying to publish my web app to MS Azure, with the help of [this website](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-continuous-delivery-use-vso/#step3).

I've run into some troubles though, which I can't quite find the source of. The builder is telling me it can't find 'ISFramework', which is a custom project of ours, we use as a reference for other projects. [Screenshot of error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSevy.png)

Though in the actual class there is no error message. It can find it just fine and while debugging the whole thing works. [Screenshot of one of the classes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1V1k.png)

Does this have something to do with the fact I'm using 2 projects for my web app? Or the fact that ISFrameworks is an external source?

EDIT: We are fairly sure the .dll of that external project isn't being added in the (live) build, though we aren't sure yet how to fix this.

Comment: Check your build configuration and ensure that there is a check beside the project you are referencing.

Comment: Could you explain that a bit more please? What exactly do I have to check? The link to the solution is specified correctly

Comment: In Visual Studio, go to the Build menu, then Configuration Manager. Ensure  that all the projects you need are selected for build.

Comment: Ah right, thanks for the clarification, but both projects are included. Their configuration is set on 'Debug'. Build is checked on and deploy is checked off. Do I have to change one of those?

Comment: You should be doing a release build for a deploy.

Comment: Mmhm, I've set the Active solution configuration on Release instead of debug, but that didn't fix anything. I also can't click on the checkboxes for deploy for some reason.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://blogs.technet.com/b/cbernier/archive/2013/09/24/deploy-your-web-application-to-windows-azure-from-with-visual-studio.aspx

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but I wanted to thank you again. The blogpost was very helpful, exactly what I needed. I managed to publish my website to Azure, though it can't access our internal databases. Anyway that's problems for us. Thanks again!